# how to activate Email Relay?

Tags: email, email-relay

As per salesforce documentation we could active the email relay:
From Setup, enter Email Relay Activation in the Quick Find box, then select Email Relay Activation.

I am using standard system admin profile and it has modify all data permission.

But I could not find out the menu. What could be the reason?

Comment: check if this feature is available in your org

Comment: how to check? as per this doc https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005793&language=en_US it should be available automatically

Comment: What org edition are you using? the doc states what editions are supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted salesforce support and they have enabled the email relay. Now I am able to configure email relay.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a permission issue. Make sure that the user attempting to enable Email Relaying has the permission "Modify All Data" on their profile.

Comment: I am using standard system admin profile and modify all data permission enabled

Comment: Try following the actual path Setup | Email Administration | Email Relay Activation

Comment: :) I have checked almost all the menu. could not find this option

Comment: Haha alright. I just tried this in my Dev and cannot see it either. I will keep digging and let you know what I find.